# awk temperature file to 3 files

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I have file with last temperature values from digitemp.

cat /sensors/digitemp/last_meteo

```
a:3:{
s:16:"28DAF82D05000055";d:4.55999999999999960920149533194489777088165283203125;
s:16:"28DAE32C050000D6";d:19.379999999999999005240169935859739780426025390625;
s:16:"28F5C92D0500008E";d:20.129999999999999005240169935859739780426025390$
```

I would like to awk that file to get only 3 values to 3 files.
This is my idea:

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $6}' /www/control/data/last_meteo |awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' 
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $9}' /www/control/data/last_meteo |awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' 
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $12}' /www/control/data/last_meteo |awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}'
```

That awk gives me:

```
root@router:~# awk -F':' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $6}' /www/control/data/last_meteo |awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}'
4.55
root@router:~# awk -F':' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $9}' /www/control/data/last_meteo |awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}'
19.3
root@router:~# awk -F':' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $12}' /www/control/data/last_meteo |awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}'
20.1
```

There is another way to get those values?
My tagert output:
4.55
19.37
20.12

Comment: shouldn't you be rounding the decimal points to the closest value?  4.559999 -> 4.56 instead of 4.55

Comment: Is your 4-line sample input fiel actually only 1 line? If so edit to fix that. You say you want 3 separate files output so I suspect you actaully have multiple lines in your input file, not just one. If so, show that. Basically - show us what you really want not something you think might be adequate but isn't actually what you have for input nor what you want for output.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use second `awk` with `substr` (fixed 4 symbols), use `printf` with 2 digits after the floating point:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C awk -F':' '{printf "%.2f\n", $6}' /www/control/data/last_meteo
```

The rest lines are changed the same way.

Comment: `LC_NUMERIC` helps the people whose system decimal point symbol is comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"};{if ($0 ~ /^s:/) {printf("%-.2f ",$4)}}' /www/control/data/last_meteo
```

> 4.56 19.38 20.13

The input field separator is set in `BEGIN` (`-F` works too). You don't need to set the output field separator. Only lines that begin with `"s:"` are considered by the rest of the `awk` program. You can make that more restrictive, e.g. `($0 ~ /s:16:"2/)`. The `printf` does not by default create a line feed, so the output is shown on the same line. The `%-.2f` prints the number with 2 decimal digits followed by a space as you'd shown in your example output.

Comment: Put conditions in the condition section, not in the action section: `awk -F':' '/^s:/{printf "%-.2f ",$4}' /www/control/data/last_meteo`